# Elasticsearch query for empty type give error and not working?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

Suppose I have a type 'audit_ssn' and has not any doc, mapping is like:

```
protected $audit_ssn_mapping_properties = array(
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'audit_ssn',
    'body' => [
        'audit_ssn' => [
            '_source' => [
                'type' => 'string',
                'analyzer' => 'standard'
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'session_id' => array("type" =>  "string"),
                'user_id'    => array(
                    'type'      => 'nested',
                    'properties' => array(
                        'id'            => array('type' => 'string'),
                        'first_name'    => array('type' => 'string'),
                        'last_name'     => array('type' => 'string'),
                        "unique_user_id" => array("type" => "string")
                    )
                ),
                'date'         => array(
                    'type'   => 'date',
                    'format' =>'YYYY-MM-dd||YYYY-MM-dd||MM/dd/yyyy||yyyy/MM/dd'
                ),
                'time' => array(
                    'type'   => 'date',
                    'format' => 'HH:mm:ss'
                )
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

Now when i want to run bellow query problem occur.

```
GET my_index/audit_ssn/_search
{
   "query":{
     "filtered":{
        "filter":{
            "and":[
                {
                    "nested":{
                        "path":"user_id",
                        "query":{
                            "terms":{
                                "user_id.id":["1000001"],
                                "minimum_match":1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
     }
  }
}
```

and the error is like:

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[my_index] [nested] failed to find nested object under path [user_id]]; }{[y0tlRvUzQ8SyyHheSxcd2g][my_index][1]: SearchParseException[[my_index][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure
```

How to solve this problem ? 
Is there any way to check if type is not empty then query should run ?
Or how to modify this query to return empty result ?

Comment: It should not return any exception if there is no document found. This exception shows that it is unable to find `nested` element with name `user_id`.

Comment: @Richa if i delete the type with `curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/my_index/audit_ssn` what happen ? does this remove mapping and settings of type ? if yes, so i should put mapping before searching every time ? yeah.

Comment: this will delete all those documents which have type `audit_ssn`. Though on searching this will return something like this: `{"took":4,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}`

Comment: @Richa But after delete when i search with simple `GET my_index/audit_ssn/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {
    }
  }
}` out put is like `{"took":4,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hi‌​ts":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}` But with above search query exception occur.

Comment: Which version of ES are u using??

Comment: @Richa I use from `1.7`

Comment: `curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/my_index/audit_ssn` . This will remove the mappings too.

Comment: Use `curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query' -d '{
    "query" : { 
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}'` to delete only the documents not mapping. Will not work for 2.x versions.

Comment: @Richa Thank you, in reality i will do not do that, now its in local, and when i did that, and then searched exception occurred.